# Bunch of errors when running monerod. ERROR cn src/cryptonote_core

Tags: monerod, cryptonote, error-log

Is this normal during syncing? I just downloaded .11 and ran monerod on ubuntu.

2017-09-18 19:28:28.513 [P2P0]  ERROR   cn  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:662 Exception at [core::handle_incoming_txs()], what=Error finding txpool tx meta: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a secondary error which happens after a DB error. The DB may or may not be corrupted. The recovery steps, in increasing order of violence:

- restart monerod
- restart monerod adding --db-salvage
- remove the ~/.bitmonero/lmdb directory

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the hidden `~/.bitmonero` folder and then reran `monerod` again and it worked. It is possible that the problem was due to a permissions issue.